# How to format a float value in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (NSString *)_stringToFloat:(NSNumber *)number {
    if (number && number > 0) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[number floatValue]];
    }
    return @"0.0";
}
```

Using:

```
_lblAppointmentFee.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[self_stringToFloat:[_dicObject objectForKeyNotNull:@"rate"]]];
```

How can I can return "5.21" for a value of 5.21 and return "5" for a value of 5.00?

Comment: Please make appropriate title. I need help Obj-C isn’t good title at all

Comment: Is that doing exactly what you want ==> `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[number floatValue]]` What are you asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `NSNumberFormatter`. Set the desired fraction digits.

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
nf.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
nf.minimumFractionDigits = 0;
nf.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
NSString *result = [nf stringFromNumber:@(5.12)];
```

This gives a result of "5.12" while:

```
result = [nf stringFromNumber:@(5.00)];
```

gives a result of "5".

This also has the added bonus of properly formatting the result based on the user's locale.